# How does Google Cloud Run spin up instantly

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-run

So, I really like the idea of server-less. I came across Google Cloud Functions and Google Cloud Run.

So google cloud functions are individual functions, which is a broad perspective, I assume google must be securely running on a huge nodejs server. And it contains all the functions of all the google consumers and fulfils the request using unique URLs. Now, Google takes care of the cost of this one big server and charges users for every hit their function gets. So its pay to use. And makes sense.

But when it comes to Cloud Run. I fail to understand how does it work. Obviously the container must not always be running because then they will simply charge a monthly basis instead of a per-hit basis, just like a normal VM where docker image is deployed. But no, in reality, they charge on per hit basis, that means they spin up the container when a request arrives. So, I don't understand how does it spin it up so fast?  The users have the flexibility of running any sort of environment, that means the docker container could contain literally anything. Maybe a full-fledged Linux OS. How does it load up the environment OS so quickly and fulfils the request? Well, maybe it maintains the state of the machine and shut it down when not in use, but even then, it will require a decent amount of time to restore the state.

So how does google really does it? How is it able to spin up a customer's container in literally no time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The idea of fast spinning-up sandboxes containers (that run on their own kernel for security reasons) have been around for a pretty long time. For example, [Intel Clear Linux Containers](https://clearlinux.org/downloads/containers) and [Firecracker](https://firecracker-microvm.github.io/) provide fast startup through various optimizations.

As you can imagine, implementing something like this would require optimizations at many layers (scheduling, traffic serving, autoscaling, image caching...).

Without giving away Google’s secrets, we can probably talk about image storage and caching: Just like how VMs use `initramfs` to pre-cache the state of the VM,  instead of reading all the files from harddisk and following the boot sequence, we can do similar tricks with containers.

Google uses a similar solution for Cloud Run, called [gVisor](https://gvisor.dev). It's a user-space virtualization technique (not an actual VMM or hypervisor). To run containers on a Linux-like environment, gVisor doesn't need to boot a Linux kernel from scratch (because gVisor reimplements the linux kernel in go!).

You’ll find many optimizations on other serverless platforms across most cloud providers (such as how to keep a container instance around, should you be predictively scheduling inactive containers before the load arrives). I recommend reading the [Peeking Behind the Curtains of Serverless Platforms](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eswift/papers/atc18-serverless.pdf) paper to get an idea about what are the problems in this space and what are cloud providers trying to optimize for speed and cost.

Comment: You are awesome!!

Answer (score 2):

You have to decouple the containers to the VMs. The second link of Dustin is great because if you understand the principles of Kubernetes (and more if you have a look to Knative), it's easy to translate this to Cloud Run.

You have a pool of resources (Nodes in Kubernetes, the VM in fact with CPU and memory) and on these resources, you can run container: 1, 2, 1000 per VM, maybe, you don't know and  you don't care. The power of the container, is the ability to be packaged with all the dependency that it needs. Yes, I talked about package because your container isn't an OS, it contains the dependencies for interacting with the host OS.

For preventing any problem between container from different project/customer, the container run into a sandbox (GVisor, first link of Dustin).

So, there is no VM to start and to stop, no VM to create when you deploy a Cloud Run services,... It's only a start of your container on existing resources. It's also for this reason that you need to have a stateless container, without disks attached to it.

***Do you want 3 "secrets"?***

1. It's exactly the same things with Cloud Functions! Your code is packaged into a container and deploy exactly as it's done with Cloud Run.
2. The underlying platform that manages Cloud Functions and Cloud Run is the same. That's why the behavior and the feature are very similar! Cloud Functions is longer to deploy because Google need to build the container for you. With Cloud Run the container is already built.
3. Your Compute Engine instance is also managed as a container on the Google infrastructure! More generally, all is container at Google!

Comment: this explains alot. 
when you say **"I talked about package because your container isn't an OS, it contains the dependencies for interacting with the host OS."** , I kind of understand it, its like I can almost feel it but not being able to wrap my head around it, by any chance you have something i can read upon? Once again, appreciate your informative answer.